# JavaScript with database

Tags: javascript, database

I want to be able to CRUD a database with JavaScript. I'm probably looking for a NoSQL solution.
Can you please point me into the right direction?

**EDIT:**
I want to be able to use this for apps built with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. e.g. Using PhoneGap.

Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript on the server, or in the browser? (Not gonna happen, if you're thinking "browser.")

Comment: Sounds dangerous.  Keep in mind that users can modify your javascript before they post data...

Comment: I'd take a look at Nodejs with DBSlayer:  http://blogupstairs.com/library-2/javascript-library-2/accessing-a-mysql-database-from-node-js-with-dbslayer/

Comment: I've edited the question, sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this client side (likely inside a browser) [Taffy DB](http://taffydb.com/) is probably the ticket. I played with it and decided it wasn't the right solution, but it's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a Javascript Database you should take a look into **[Taffy DB](http://taffydb.com/)**.